# Please solve this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I think I'm missing something here.
Please include steps solving this equation to $x$.

$$0=\cos^2{x}+\cos{x}-\sin^2{x}$$

Comment: Replace $\sin^2 x$ by $1-\cos^2 x$. We get a quadratic equation.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Just beat me to giving the same hint.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @WarrenHill It's from last years math exam which I'm currently studying for

Comment: @WarrenHill:  You might want to take the trouble to write out an answer, as a model for OP.

Comment: @user1211030 Any time you have to solve an equation in only trigonometric functions, the solution ALWAYS involves a substitution (or else your professors wouldn't even give it to you).  So your first step should always be to check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

\begin{align}
\cos^2x+\cos x-\sin^2x&=0\\
\cos^2x+\cos x-(1-\cos^2x)&=0\\
2\cos^2x+\cos x-1&=0\\
(2\cos x-1)(\cos x+1)&=0
\end{align}

Comment: seriously! How hard was it?

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos x=-(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)\iff\cos2x=\cos(\pi+x)$$

$$2x=2n\pi\pm(\pi+x)$$ where $n$ is any integer